# ViewModel List property is null when Command is executed

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

This is easier explained by codes:

```
    private List<MatchHistory> matchHistories;
    public List<MatchHistory> MatchHistories
    {
        get
        {
            return matchHistories;
        }
        set
        {
            matchHistories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Command GetMatchHistoriesCmd
    {
        get;
    }

    private void ExecuteGetMatchHistories()
    {
        MatchHistories = Helper.GetMatchHistories();            // This returns List<MatchHistory>
    }
```

Debugging it breaks when it tries to assign to MatchHistories, but why did it gets null when GetMatchHistories returns an object? Shouldn't it just assign that object to the MatchHistories property?

```
    public static List<MatchHistory> GetMatchHistories()
    {
        List<MatchHistory> mh = new List<MatchHistory>();
        mh.Add(new MatchHistory { match_id = "1234", right_win = true });
        return mh;
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain the GetMatchHistories returns a list List<MatchHistory>?

Comment: Yes, because I can see the Count of the result when I debug inside

Comment: Please show that method. That is where the issue could be.

Comment: Added the method. It returns hardcoded result, I'm just trying to learn MVVM now :\

Comment: I think the issue is whatever you are doing when OnPropertyChanged() is triggered. If you comment out OnPropertyChanged, it will work. Then you can see what you are doing in OnPropertyChanged that is causing the issue. Also if you past the error you are getting, I can help point out the issue.

Comment: Hey, that was really weird. I commented out the OnPropertyChanged, compiled it, and undo it back and now it works. Really weird...